# StarTeam check out files from all folders including subfolders and files on win7

Tags: version-control, windows-7, starteam

I need to checkout files from StarTeam 12.0 into my local folders.

The folder tree on starteam is like :

```
folder_top
    folder_level_1a
        subfolder_level_2
               subfolder_level_3
    folder_level_1b
        folder_level_2
               folder_level_3
```

But, after checking out all files in my specified local folder, all files (of folder_top) are located in one folder. All subfolders and their files are not checked out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried right-clicking on folder_top and selecting the "Create Working Folders" option first?

Answer (score 1):

Selecting your top folder, then selecting `Check Out All` from the File menu will check out all the files in that folder and descendant folders.

Also, note that clicking the `All Descendants` button will show all files in descendant folders as well as the selected folder.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have checked out to a specific location.  There is (or at least used to be) an option in the check-out dialog to override the location of the checkout, and in this case all of the files would be placed in that specific location.  What you need to do in StarTeam is set your Alternate (not Default) Working Folder for the View, and then all of the files you check out will be put in the relative location based on the folder name.  Do not override the working folders at the folder level, because this will cause your folder structure not to be mirrored.  If you keep it simple and always set the Alternate Working Folder at the View and nowhere else, all your checkouts should go to the expected location.  Don't override in the checkout dialog.  Keep in mind, however, that even if you don't override the default working folders at the folder level, someone else on your team might.  In those cases you can override their overrides by setting your alternate working folder to the folder name.  This is one of the most painful and poorly designed aspects of StarTeam and always has been.  Despite years and years of proposed enhancements to fix this, they have done nothing to address these issues.  Be vigilant!